# Recursive FFT Error?

Tags: java, math, fft, polynomial-math, ifft

Given below is my java program for FFT. For the input {0,2,3,-1} its returns a false output in complex point representation.

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class test{
static double s[]={0,2,3,-1};
static double[][] re=new double[s.length][2];
static double[][] er=new double[s.length][2];
static double[][][] ma=new double[s.length][s.length][2];
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double[][] aray1=new double[s.length][2];
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    {
        aray1[i][0]=s[i];
        aray1[i][1]=0;
    }
    re=fft(aray1,1);
    for(int i=0;i<re.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(""+re[i][0]+"+i*"+re[i][1]);
    }
            //Inverse FFT
    re=fft(re,-1);
    for(int i=0;i<re.length;i++)
    {
        //System.out.println("sdsfbv /n /n");
        System.out.println(""+(re[i][0]/s.length)+"+i*"+((re[i][1])/s.length));
    }


}
public static double[][] complexmult(double[][] a,double[][] b)
{
    double[][] e=new double[1][2];

    return e;
}
public static double[][] fft(double[][] a, int c)
{
    double[][] de=new double[1][2];
    int n=a.length;

    if(n==1)
    {
        return a;
    }
    double wnx=Math.cos(c*2*Math.PI/n);
    double wny=Math.sin(c*2*Math.PI/n);
    double wx=1;
    double wy=0;
    double[][] y=new double[n][2];
    double[] e=new double[n];
    double[][] a0=new double[n/2][2];
    double[][] a1=new double[n/2][2];
    double[][] y0=new double[n][2];
    double[][] y1=new double[n][2];
    for(int i=0,k=0,j=0;i<n;i=i+1)
    {
        if((i%2)==0)
        {

            a0[k][0]=a[i][0];
            a0[k][1]=a[i][1];
            k=k+1;
        }
        else
        {

            a1[j][0]=a[i][0];
            a1[j][1]=a[i][1];
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
    y0=fft(a0,c);
    y1=fft(a1,c);       
    for(int k=0;k<=((n/2)-1);k++)
    {
        double m1=((wx*y1[k][0])-(wy*y1[k][1]));
        double m2=((wx*y1[k][1])+(wy*y1[k][0]));
        y[k][0]= y0[k][0]+m1;
        y[k][1]=y0[k][1]+m2;
        y[k+(n/2)][0]=y0[k][0]-m1;
        y[k+(n/2)][1]=y0[k][1]-m2;
        wx=((wx*wnx)-(wy*wny));
        wy=((wx*wny)+(wy*wnx));
    }
    return y;       
}
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
    4.0+i*0.0
    -3.0+i*1.8369701987210297E-16
    2.0+i*0.0
    -3.0+i*-1.8369701987210297E-16
```

However the output should be:

```
    4.0+i*0.0
    -3.0+i*-3
    2.0+i*0.0
    -3.0+i*3
```

It seems that there is a logic error somewhere in fft() that I am missing. Can someone help me locate it?

Comment: "Please trace program" ... no, that's what your debugger is for.

Comment: I mean, There is no syntax error in the program but i am missing fft logic and may be i am using some wrong usage of variables. Thats what i want some one to help me in...

Comment: @BrianRoach How else would you help solve any problem but trace through the program? He has likely looked through the program and cannot find where he is making a logic error, much like 75% of the questions on this website.

Comment: I don't help him solve his problem. By definition it's *too localized* and not a valid question for SO. The fact that you keep repeating your objections to SO's guidelines really has no bearing.

Comment: @kyle Rogers Thanks for understanding what i meant

Comment: @BrianRoach "I don't help him solve his problem" If you aren't going to help people solve problems and answers questions, why are you on a Q&A site? As for "The fact that you keep repeating your objections to SO's guidelines really has no bearing." I don't even know what you are trying to say. Repeating my objections? Where else have I objected? Please try not to be so pretentious. Yes, this question is localized, so why not direct him to CodeReview rather than be an ass?

Comment: @KyleRogers This question is off topic for CodeReview. CR is for correct code only.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
    wx=((wx*wnx)-(wy*wny));
    wy=((wx*wny)+(wy*wnx));
```

You are clobbering the value of `wx` by replacing it with the new one in the first line before using it to compute the new value of `wy` in the second line.  So, the result of the complex multiplication is not correct.  Also, although this is not causing the error, there is no need to initialize `y0` and `y1` since they are set by the recursive calls to `fft`.  There are also other unused variables.